# Update GeoJSONDataSource in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a problem with the update function for GeoJSONDataSource in bokeh.
For the following code I take two scripts - which are working well - and add them to one.

But when I do `bokeh serve app` I get the following Error message and I don't understand why: `304 GET /app`

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, GeoJSONDataSource, Div, LinearColorMapper, LogColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets.inputs import DatePicker, MultiSelect, Select
import datetime as dt
import pickle
import os
import geopandas as gpd


lin_color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=['#FFFFFF', '#FAFEFF', '#F6FCFF'])
log_color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette=['#FFFFFF', '#FAFEFF', '#F6FCFF'])
```

This is from one of the examples of bokeh.

```
desc = Div(text=open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates/index.html")).read())
```

Here is the connection to my DWH

```
# get data from DWH
table = ...
```

Next step I get the ready polygons

```
# get pickle with geometry data
home_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, 'static', 'geometry.pickle')

with open(file_dir, 'rb') as file:
   geometry = pickle.load(file)
```

And merge them with my data

```
table = geometry.merge(table, how='inner', right_on='delivery_region', left_on='geometry')
```

Only some Slider stuff (I cut a lot of them for this try)

```
# Create Input Sliders
min_date = DatePicker(title='Start',
                  min_date=dt.date(2017, 1, 1),
                  max_date=dt.date.today(),
                  value=dt.date(2018, 1, 1))
max_date = DatePicker(title='End',
                  min_date=dt.date(2017, 1, 1),
                  max_date=dt.date.today(),
                  value=dt.date.today())
```

Adding a GeoJSONDataSource with a geojson smaple from the web

```
# adding the source with some sample date from the web (must be geojson)
geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson='{'
                                   '"type": "Feature",'
                                   '"geometry": {'
                                   '"type": "Point",'
                                   '"coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]'
                                   '},'
                                   '"properties": {'
                                   '"name": "Dinagat Islands"'
                                   '}'
                                   '}')
```

Create the hover tool

```
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("Region", "@region"),
    ("Value", "@value")])
```

build the plot

```
p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=800, x_axis_location=None, 
y_axis_location=None, tools=[hover])
p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_color={'field': 'value', 'transform': lin_color_mapper}, line_color='white', line_width=0.1, source=geo_source)
```

define a function to select the right data for the sliders

```
def select_table():
    selected = table[(table['date'] >= min_date.value) & (table['date'] <= max_date.value)]
    return selected
```

define my update function to get the desired data. Here, the GeoJSONDataSource is updated

```
def update():
    df = select_table()
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
    group = df.groupby('region')
    value = group.agg({'date': 'count', 'geometry': 'first'}).reset_index(drop=False)

    gdf['region'] = value['region']
    gdf['value'] = value['date']
    gdf['geometry'] = value['geometry']
    gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:2263'}
    gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2263'})
    gjson = gdf.to_json()
    geo_source.geojson = gjson
```

Here I create the updates for the sliders

```
controls = [min_date, max_date]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

inputs = widgetbox(*controls)
```

Only layout stuff from the slider example of bokeh

```
l = layout([
   [desc],
   [inputs, p], ])

update()
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = 'Choropleth Map Test'
```